# How to convert my floating number to feed my Neural Network?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, perceptron, backpropagation

I've been reading some online tutorials about Neurons, Percepton and Multi Layer Perceptron concepts. Now, I would like to implement the concept in my own examples. What I would like to do is to implement the following simple algorithm into my network:

Assuming we have 4 floating numbers `minus1`, `plus1`, `minus2`, `plus2`

```
if (minus2>plus2) and (minus1<plus1) then return 1
else if (minus2<plus2) and (minus1>plus1) then return -1
else return 0
```

But here are my concerns:

1. How do I feed my network with such numbers: 63.8990, -165.177, 1.33001 or 0.98401?
2. How should I choose the number of inputs as I have 4 numbers but I don't know if I should use just 4 inputs or convert everything in bits first and choose the number of inputs according to the numbers of related bits?
3. Considering the 3 types of output (1,-1,0) should I need 3 neurons in my output layer each one representing a specific type of answer or maybe I should train the network to learn seperately each kind of answer (1 for the first network, -1 for the second and 0 for the last one) ?

Thank you all in advance for even reading and your help is highly appreciated

Stephane

Answer (score 1):

The question's abit vague. I shall interpret it as:

You are trying to implement the function `f(m1, p1, m2, p2)` (definition given by that `if` clause) using neural networks.

For (1), you need to consider how you are representing the network, which is affected by what type of network you are using.

For (2), to train the network, you'll need to use use true values (i.e. instances of `m1, p1, m2, p2, and f(m1, p1, m2, p2)`).

For (3), you don't really have 3 *types* of outputs. Rather, you have 3 possible outputs. Of course, it is possible to train 3 networks to respond when that particular output is the answer, but you can also (with the proper type of network) achieve the same with a network with one output.

Comment: For (3) you can have 1 network with 3 output nodes labeled (1,-1,0) and a 'winner takes all' strategy for deciding the network's response.

Comment: agreed. theoretically equivalent to having one more layer that is static and has that transfer function.

Answer (score 1):

1) I'm not sure that it matters what kind of numbers you use to feed your NN (Neural Network [or perceptron]). This is to say that you could make the 4 input nodes accept a signed floating point number (or signed Decimal if its available) This way you can have the inputs all accepting the same type of data for processing. As you will multiply the input by a weighted value you would most likely get a float or a decimal value anyway within the NN.

2) I would generally say that as you have 4 data points, that 4 inputs to the NN is a good starting point!

3) As for the output it is perfectly possibly to have one output node for the entire NN. To use this design there will need to be a threshold function which takes the final output from the NN and converts it to usable values. in your example I would suggest that anything below -0.5 you classify as -1, any output between -0.5 and +0.5 you classify as 0 and anything above +0.5 you classify as 1.

e.g.

```
Value           | Output
----------------|----------
< -0.5          | -1
-0.5 < x < +0.5 | 0
x > +0.5        | +1
```